# Is cardinality of sigma-algebra for two independent random variables is the sum of cardinalities of two sigma-algebras?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

Let's say that there are two independent r.v. $A$ and $B$. Is $card \{\sigma(A,B)\}$ the sum of $card \{\sigma(A)\}$ and $card \{\sigma(B)\}$, where $card$ is cardinality (the number of elements in $\sigma$)? Can you give a counter example or some ideas for the proof?

Comment: Independence requires  a probability measure. Questions about sigma algebras  generated by random variables  do not have anything to do with independence.

Comment: If $A=0$ and $B=1$ then $card (\sigma(A,B))=card (\sigma (A))=card (\sigma(B))=2$ since all three sigma algebras have only the empty set the whole space in them.